# How to generate multiple rows based on a single record when join a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `User` and `Post`. User has many posts, so `user_id` is the foreign key.

User:

```
id | name | base 
---+------+-------
1  | User1|  5
```

Post:

```
id | content |  min | max | user_id
---+---------+------+-----+--------
1  | Test    |   8  |  10 | 1
2  | Test2   |   10 |  15 | 1
```

There could also have other table to join(Which is not show in the example). In general, I can joins the posts and other tables:

```
SELECT users.id, users.content, posts.min, posts.max, posts.content, ...
FROM users
JOIN table_1
ON condition_1
JOIN table_2
ON condition_2
JOIN posts
ON users.id = posts.user_id
```

Now I want to get users, but join posts and extend the posts based on `user.base`, which will seperate id=1 post into two records. So finally I want to get 3 records:

```
user.id | user.name | user.base | post.id | post.content | post.min | post.max | post.user_id
--------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------------+----------+----------+----------
1       | User1     | 5         | 1       | Test         | 5        | 8        | 1
1       | User1     | 5         | 1       | Test         | 8        | 10       | 1
1       | User1     | 5         | 2       | Test2        | 10       | 15       | 1
```

Is it possible to get the result via SQL?

Comment: I don't fully understand how the logic generalizes.  What if the base is 9 or 15 or 23?

Comment: If you join you will get only 2 records.

Comment: what if base is between min and max or even greater than max? What if base equals one of these values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The condition could be customised based on some sample comparison. So if it's between min and max, say 9, then we got one from 8-9, and one from 9-10

Answer (score 0):

I guess below query would do the job if i understood it correctly ,

```
(select u.id as uid,u.name,u.base,p.id,p.content, base as min,min as max,user_id 
from users u,posts p where u.id = p.user_id
and min = (select min(min) from posts p1 where p1.user_id = u.id))
union 
select u.id as uid,u.name,u.base,p.id,p.content,min, max,user_id from users
u,posts p where u.id = p.user_id
order by uid,min
```

[image]

dbfiddle example with whole solution : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=592d8eb5803c11b2a30cac388344a402

**UPDATE :** To join the results with other tables,use the above query as inline view and join with tables with conditions as desired.

Lets assume another table user_addr that has address details for all users and user_id is the foreign key that references user.id

```
select uid,name,base,pid,content,min,max,magic_table.user_id,addr_typ,addrline1,addrline2,city,postcode,prov,country
from 
((select u.id  as uid,u.name,u.base,p.id as pid,p.content, base as min,min as max,user_id 
from users u,posts p where u.id = p.user_id
order by min asc
fetch first 1 rows only)
union
select u.id as uid,u.name,u.base,p.id as pid,p.content,min, max,user_id from users
u,posts p where u.id = p.user_id) magic_table, user_addr
where magic_table.user_id = user_addr.user_id
```

Output :
[image]

dbfiddle link with solution : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ea697bbf1502857834b461edd8ccf447

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I also need to join other tables, do I need to join in each part and union together?

Comment: If it is an equi-join, then treat the above query as inline view and join with other tables.If you may update the question with details, should be able to clarify better.

Comment: Updated solution.